# Modules on Python which are useful for missing Word/Letter prediction in text paragraphs from a coprpus

Tags: data-mining, python, text-mining, predictive-modeling

Can someone please recommend me some Python packages which I can use for missing word prediction in a paragraph of text. The missing words are a part of existing semantic list of words.( List of missing words are a common set of words like was ,were etc). If there are better packages in R which can help me with this  it would be very useful if you post it here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be exactly (or at least very similar to) that in the [Billion Word Imputation](https://www.kaggle.com/c/billion-word-imputation) challenge at Kaggle. Some of the approaches discussed in the forums might help you out. My initial thoughts for useful tools/methods would be word2vec, the stanford NLP tools and sklearn.